# Dropdown List for plugin

Tags: php, wordpress

I am developing a plugin, but I am clearly missing something.

My options for the check boxes I have created are saving, but I have also created a dropdown menu. The drop down menu doesn't save my selection for some reason.  Thoughts?

```
//add for settings page    
add_settings_field("add-sizing", "Icon size", "add_sizing_function", "rcktcld-social", "admin_settings_section");


//register        
register_setting("admin_settings_section", "add-sizing");

        <?php function add_sizing_function() { ?>
            <select name="add-sizing">
                <option value="60" <?php selected( "add-sizing", 60 ); echo esc_attr( __( 'Select page' ) ); ?> >X-Large</option>
                <option value="48" <?php selected( "add-sizing", 48 ); echo esc_attr( __( 'Select page' ) ); ?> >Large</option>
                <option value="32" <?php selected( "add-sizing", 32 ); echo esc_attr( __( 'Select page' ) ); ?> >Medium</option>
                <option value="24" <?php selected( "add-sizing", 24 ); echo esc_attr( __( 'Select page' ) ); ?> >Small</option>

            </select>
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

They are probably saving fine, but you're not using the [`selected`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/selected) function properly: it compares two values for equality, and `"add-sizing"` is never equal to a number.

You'll want to replace the first argument with the actual option value, like so:

```
$add_sizing_setting = get_option( 'add-sizing' );

...

<option value="60" <?php selected( $add_sizing_setting, 60 ); .....
<option value="48" <?php selected( $add_sizing_setting, 48 ); .....
...
```

Comment: So i tried that, still not?

<select name="add-sizing">
  <option value="60" <?php selected( 60 ); ?> >X-Large</option>
        <option value="48" <?php selected( 48 ); ?> >Large</option>
        <option value="32" <?php selected( 32 ); ?> >Medium</option>
        <option value="24" <?php selected( 24 ); ?> >Small</option> 
    </select>

Comment: Sorry about that, I clarified the answer.

Comment: bang on!  Thank you  my huge miss was $add_sizing_setting = get_option( 'add-sizing' );  i had it in another function

Comment: can i buy you a coffee or something? for reals. i looked at that for an hour, couldnt figure it out. send me a message.

Comment: :-) That's really nice of you, but it's not necessary! You already gave me two gifts: an opportunity to help, and your appreciation. So thank you! Oh, and good luck with the wp settings API - it's horrible. I ended up writing my own and storing all plugin settings in a single serialized option. All I have to do now to add an option is add an entry to an array structure.